# Why is this not working on Firefox, Chrome or Safari but on IE?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a student and cannot wrap my head around why this isn't working.

```
function addedToCart(x)
            {
            alert( x.value + " has been added to cart\nPress OK to continue.");
            }


<a href="#" value="blue circle" onclick="addedToCart(this)">
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the modern browsers, your code is wrong." Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Comment: @Rob, In my professor's mantra "it worked on firefox, but not IE? your code is wrong"

I test in chrome first usually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `value` is not a **valid** attribute for an anchor `<a>`. It's intended to be used for form elements, such as `input` or `select`.

A more appropriate (and with valid markup) solution would be to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes, and then fetch it using `getAttribute` as suggested by @Jeffrey Sweeney:

```
<a href="#" data-value="blue circle" onclick="addedToCart(this)">
```

And then:

```
alert( x.getAttribute("data-value"))
```

Comment: so this is the valid reason why Internet Explorer was running it properly?

Comment: Yes. Standardized attributes can be referenced with a simple dot operator, where unspecified attributes require a `getAttribute` function call. For example, `x.href` would work in any browser.  @user1690192 the `value` attribute is not standardized, so IE was at fault here.

Comment: @user1690192: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thank you both, unfortunately, my professor is not enforcing too many HTML standards. For what the class requires i believe we are working on HTML 4.01 (last standard?) thanks for the HTML5 info though :)

Comment: If your professor isn't enforcing HTML standards, you really need a new professor. The only reason the Internet works at all is because we all agree to "speak the same language."

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `getAttribute` function:

```
alert( x.getAttribute("value") + " has been added to cart\nPress OK to continue.");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute

Comment: No prob. Depending on how you set the attribute for an element, this isn't always required. Inline values "usually" require it though.

Answer (score 0):

2 things `value` is not a native property from `<a` and you are not closing with `</a>`

I hope this code below will help you to understand one simular approach to make it work:

```
<script>
    function addedToCart(x) {
        alert(x.value + " has been added to cart\nPress OK to continue.");
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="addedToCart(document.getElementById('txt1'))">blue circle</a>
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="some value"/>
```

IE has also it's own way to interpret html, it adds more **bad** than **good** because it enforces not having a pattern

Comment: I think the user's code was just a portion of their entire sample. This code snippet achieves something slightly different.